# VBA - Print 2nd Page of WebForm with .ExecWB

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, printing, webforms

I am using ***Object*.ExecWB** to print out a webpage in my VBA code. Specifically, I am using this line (IE is an "Application.InternetExplorer" Object):

```
Const OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
Const OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
IE.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER
```

It does as it should in terms of printing the page, however, it does not print the *correct* page.

The webpage is a webform with the same URL and the code I have does the right things to get to the correct page that I want to print (the 2nd "page" or "screen" of the form), however the command still prints the first page.

If I step through the code line-by-line, it prints the correct page, however, when I let it rip on it's own, it prints the first page only, even though I can clearly see IE navigating to the second page before it prints.

I have tried putting sleep commands into the code, but to no avail. Anyone have any ideas?

For clarity sake here is some snippet of the code I am trying (code uses a with statement on IE.document):

```
   'this gets to the correct form page
   .getElementsByName("in_1060_1").item(0).Value = "1"
   .parentWindow.setCursorPosition "400", "HATSForm" 
   .parentWindow.ms "[enter]", "HATSForm"

    IEWait IE 'calls a sub that sleeps when IE is busy or not in readystate
    Sleep 5000

    'I then hit the 'OK' button to get to the 2nd page where the info I need to print is
    .parentWindow.ms "[enter]", "HATSForm"

    'yet it still prints out the first page! Ugh!
    Const OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
    Const OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
    IE.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER
```

Comment: Have you considered hiding the content of your first page using JavaScript and then restoring the visibility afterward?  If that workaround isn't suitable, you may be able to leverage a print template: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250434.aspx

Comment: Thanks @QZSupport - This was a project from last year. I ended up sending a print screen to Word and printing the word document. A bit convoluted but it worked nicely in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up sending a Print Screen to Word and printing the Word document. A bit convoluted, but it worked nicely in the end.

Sorry I don't have code used to get this to work, but it was from a previous job.